# Use nginx to redirect requests to kuberenetes services

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm looking for a way, if possible to route a request to for eg. team.mysite.com to team.default.svc.cluster.local using nginx. This way I could have multiple wordpress sites using different sub domains on my domains and working as explained above. Basically calling xyz.mysite.com would have the request forwarded to xyz.default.svc.cluster.local, provided the service exists.

Note:
I have the kube-dns service running at 10.254.0.2

Is this possible? And how exactly would I do this?

Thanks.

Edit:
Going over this again I could possibly use variables in the ngonx.conf i.e $host.$host.default.svc.cluster.conf where $host is $host.mydomain.com.
I'd need a way to let nginx resolve the kube dns services also a way to part out the xyz in xyz.mydomain.com in the nginx.conf and assigning it to $host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your nodes have a public IP address you could use an [Ingress resource](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) to do exactly what you describe. An Ingress usually defines a list of paths and their target Service, so your service should be running before you try to expose it.

[Ingress controllers](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/README.md) then dynamically configure Web servers that listen on a defined list of ports for you (typically the host ports 80 and 443 as you may have guessed) using the Ingress configuration mentioned above, and can be deployed using the Kubernetes resource type of your choice: Pod, ReplicationController, DaemonSet.

Once your Ingress rules are configured and your Ingress controller is deployed, your can point the A or CNAME DNS records of your domain to the node(s) running the actual Web server(s).

Comment: Just gone over th ingress docs; actually the process will be automated and I won't know the paths beforehand

Comment: But I'd still probably have to use an ingress controller

Comment: You're dealing with an API, so you could automate the update of the Ingress as part of your automated process.